# cloning from GitHub on Android using Terminal IDE

Tags: android, git, terminal-ide

I tried following the directions [here](http://lox-o-drome.blogspot.com/2012/08/damgit-how-to-painfully-set-up-git-on.html).

And I keep getting the following message:

> ssh: connection to git@github.com:22 exited No auth methods could be
>   used. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Steps I followed

1. Made Key
2. Copied Key to github.
3. Checked Key was working properly by running

   > ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
4. Created the file ssh-git in ~/local/bin/

   > exec ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "$@"
5. Make the file executable:

   > chmod 755 ~/local/bin/ssh-git
6. added the following line to ~/.bashrc

   > export GIT_SSH=~/local/bin/ssh-git
7. Ran this

   > git clone git@github.com/username/reponame.git
8. And I get the following error:

   > ssh: connection to git@github.com:22 exited No auth methods could be
   >   used. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 6):

As [described here](http://federico-lox.github.io/development/android-and-git-a-version-controlled-love-story.html) you can set up cloning via ssh (HTTPS is not supported) with: first, a passphrase-less key in `~/.ssh/id_pub`:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
dropbearkey -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
dropbearkey -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa | sed -n 2p > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Second, a wrapper script `~/local/bin/ssh-git` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/local/bin/ssh-git`:

```
#!/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin/bash
exec ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "$@"
```

Third, some settings in `.bashrc`. I have put it in another file included by `.bashrc` on Android only, so I can use the same `.bashrc` on other environments too:

```
export GIT_SSH=~/local/bin/ssh-git
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="USER NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="user@email.address"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

Restart Terminal IDE before this changes can be used.

There is another thread on this is at https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/issues/detail?id=26.

Comment: I used this for an entirely different device, the Onion Omega2+ which uses a version of OpenWRT.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning with the following syntax instead:

`git clone git@github.com:username/reponame`

Comment: Did you try it with the alternative syntax I posted?  In step seven you didn't use this format, with the colon.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that terminal IDE has a problem right now where it cannot resolve host names. That means instead of github.com, you must use the IP adress 
also try using `git clone https://IP/User/REPO.git`

Comment: I get "cannot exec "git-remote-https" permission denied